# Socket connection refused due to a burst of connections

Tags: c, sockets, parallel-processing, synchronization

I am using sockets in order to synchronize several remote processes.

The idea is that a process creates a pthread which manages the server side, just like that:

```
void *listener(void * in) {
  int sockfd;
  socklen_t clilen;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n = *((int *) in);

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0)
      error("ERROR opening socket");

  int option = 1;
  setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, (SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR), (char*) &option, sizeof (option));
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0)
      error("ERROR on binding");

  if (listen(sockfd, n) < 0)
      error("ERROR when listening");

  clilen = sizeof (cli_addr);
  int cnt = 0;
  while (cnt < n) {
      int newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
      if (newsockfd < 0) {
          error("ERROR on accept");
      }
      cnt++;
  }
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Meanwhile, the other processes would execute:

```
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
  error("ERROR opening socket");

server = gethostbyname(_managementHost); //managementHost);
if (server == NULL)
  error("ERROR, no such host\n");

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0)
  error("ERROR connection");

close(sockfd);
```

Now, the problem I have is when I have a lot of processes trying to connect at the same time to the server, some of them are throwing *connection refused* errors.

I guess that is because the accepts may not be ready... In fact, I have read that it could happen, but I have not found my specific case.

Could anyone shed light on the matter?

A possible solution that occurs to me, is to create a thread for each accept, but I would prefer to avoid it.

Thank you.

EDIT: corrected double initialization of socket in the server. Thanks to @Remy Lebeau.

Comment: I don't think I understand well enough what you are attempting to do.  What is supposed to be accomplished by accepting connections and then leaking them?  How does any of this produce any synchronization?  Or have you cut out some important bits that feed your synchronization and non-resource-leakage objectives?

Comment: The idea is that the first process will wait at `pthread_join` until the others have reach a given point. I only use sockets for synchronizing them, I am not interested in communicating the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the problem I have is when I have a lot of processes trying to connect at the same time to the server, some of them are throwing connection refused errors.

A listening TCP socket has a backlog of pending connections.  The 2nd parameter of `listen()` specifies how many connections are allowed to be in the backlog queue before they are accepted.  If a new client tries to connect when the backlog is full, the client is refused.  There is nothing the client or server can do about that.  It is the client's responsibility to detect the error and re-connect at a later time.

Your `listener()` is accepting clients until it reaches a designated number of connections, but you are also using that same number for the listen backlog queue size.  The number of active connections and the number of pending connections are two different things.  If you are expecting a lot of clients to connect at the same time, you need a large backlog size to avoid the refusal errors.  But that backlog should be sized proportional to the traffic you are expecting.  If you have 1000 clients, but they connect only 20 at a time, you would set the backlog to, say, 25, not 1000.

Your `listener()` has some other logic bugs.  It is calling `socket()` twice and saving the two sockets to the same `sockfd` variable, so it is leaking the first socket.  You need to remove the second call to `socket()` (the one just before `setsockopt()`).  You are also leaking the sockets that `accept()` returns.  You need to `close()` an accepted socket after you are doing using it.

Comment: So, even though a process connects and the `accept()` has not been issued yet, the client connection will remain in the backlog, right?
Regarding the bugs, you are right, I have too many `socket()` calls. However, I cannot close the socket after `accept()` because I only have one socket opened (it is only one thread that performs the `listener()`. Should I create a thread for each `accept()`? Thank you.

Comment: @SergioIserte yes, a connection remains in the backlog until removed by `accept()`. If you intend to service multiple clients at a time, you will have to create a new thread/process per accepted client (not per call to `accept()` itself), or otherwise multiplex multiple clients in a thread (such as making the sockets non-blocking and then use `select()`/`epoll()` to manage them), so you can go back to `accept()` regularly.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about what you mean with _accepted client_. What I was refering, was to create `n` threads each one calling an `accept()`. What's your point? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SergioIserte a connection is "accepted" when `accept()` returns it. You can't call `accept()` from `n` threads, it should only be called by one thread. You need to accept a client and delegate the workload for that client, and then go back to `accept()` to accept the next client. Either 1) call `accept()` in a loop and pass each client to another thread, or 2) use `select()`/`epoll()` to monitor multiple socets ay a time to be notified when to call `accept()`/`recv()`/`send()` for them. This should be covered by any decent socket book/tutorial.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. However, in my question is detailed your first option (except for the later communications, which I don't have) and it returns a _connection refused_. Moreover, I'm closing the socket as soon as I don't need it (just after all the `accepts()` have been connected. We are at the beggining again :( 
Thank you.

Comment: @SergioIserte you are closing the listening socket, not the client sockets. And I already addressed the refusal error (your clients are exceeding the backlog)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your server concurrent by calling fork to spawn a child for each client.  Easiest way to do it, IMO.  Avoids threading and will stop the connection refused errors.

EDIT:  You could also look into pre-forking your server.  You'd have to research how you want to handle locking around accept, though (if you're locking at all).